# What's the general idea on displaying 'what's new' message to user using PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Just like Twitter's pattern, one user can follow another, and the others' news containing new tweets, new photos and something like that will display on this user's homepage in time order.
I don't have any idea on this. One may follow thousands of other users, if i use 'select' to do this, there would be too much select query to do. 
If anyone please tell me a general idea on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you use `TOP` or `LIMIT` in your query to limit the amount of returned results. You could implement paging with, say, 50 messages per page, so each query will only return 50 messages.

Comment: Even using limit will also cause too much query. The difference between my application and twitter is mine has lots of tables like tweets, posts, music, video, book preference ,etc. to get news. Is it a good idea to create a new table to hold news and every time when a new photo or post is created insert id and type to this table?

Comment: I really don't know what 'too much query' is. If you mean that you want to display all new items from a lot of tables, yes, you have to write a lot of queries. Denormalisation (i.e. storing important fields from all tables in a separate `news` table) could be an option, if having a lot of queries means a severe performance impact, but it comes at the cost of more overhead when adding and updating items (you have to maintain the data in both tables). You could also look at a `UNION`.

Comment: Thank you. I'm just questioning it's performance and try to find a better way. I'll test it and speak with statics.

Answer (score 0):

u can keep track of ur records with an additional columns to status and datetime. That way you can post the latest status and datetime. Note you must write code to change the status according  to entries, meaning u must change the status of a previous record whenever a user addes new record.